# RPC clnt_call sends tcp [ FIN, ACK ] immediatly

Tags: sockets, tcp, client, rpc, nfs

I'm programing in CentOS 6.5 on VM, writing code in C

I made a call

```
client_status = clnt_call( clnt, NFSPROC3_GETATTR, 
                          (xdrproc_t)xdr_GETATTR3args, (caddr_t)&args,
                          (xdrproc_t)xdr_GETATTR3res, (caddr_t)&result, TIMEOUT);
```

where clnt is a client that i create once a use clnt_call and keep it for the next calls ( instad of creating a new one for each call )

- I still didn't realise whats the trigger for it, but occasionally i get a message "RPC: Unable to receive" which is followed by a destruction of the client and creating a new client for retransmission - which always works.
- when using tcpdump to watch what actually happened what i saw was that after the NFSPROC3_GETATTR was sent ( with all the correct information ), 60 micro sec later the client sends a TCP [ FIN, ACK ] message.

  - maybe tcp dump dropped some packets in the middle ( but i doubt it )

what can cause the connection act like this?
I've tried looking what changed between clnt_calls and the Authenticator stays the same and all the information stays the same, but maybe a long time of inactivity makes the server lose the connection and it can only be solved by creating a new client.

Answer (score 0):

The reason client send FIN after failing a clnt_call was because he got thrown to clnt_destroy and was re-created to try again

the reason I got the error in the first place was because after idle time of 6min+ the server sends FIN to the client and he ACKs back, but still acts as if the connection is active - leaving us with [half open tcp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open) connection

therefore when trying to send a message i received a RPC ERROR - Unable to receive - due to the fact that none was listening on the  other side ( server already disconnected )